# NSSortDescriptor is not working while fetching records from Core Data

Tags: core-data, nssortdescriptor

I am trying to use NSSortDescriptor in Core Data to fetch my records. Array of modal-objects doesn't get affected by sort descriptor. It gives records in same order.Here is my code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc=[self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"To_Do" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"repeatDate" ascending:NO];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[sortDescriptor release];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError * error = nil;

NSArray *arrEntity = nil;
arrEntity=[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: Your code is correct and i used the same… except my project is ARC base so i haven't used release.

Answer (score 4):

The code looks fine and should work. Since it does not there a couple of possible causes.

1. The unsorted fetch order might be the same as sorted order. This can happen sometimes if you create objects in series and use a a key like a creation date or the like.
2. Your keys might all have the same value. This can happen if you have a default value.
3. You have the wrong key or misspelled its name. You should get a complaint but it won't crash if it can't find the key.

Comment: Ok. I get it. I track my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem if I had done like this

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors.append("key")
```

But if I use

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = ["key"]
```

Then it works fine